# Building variable dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependencies

I am trying to build some variable dependencies in Python. For example, if `a = x`, `b = y` and `c = a + b`, then if `a` or `b` changes the value of `c` should be automatically updated. I am aware the Python variables and values work on the basis of tags and have been trying to work around this using `__setattr__`. I seem to be having some trouble doing this, due to the cyclic dependency in `__setattr__`.

Consider this small code snippet:

```
class DelayComponents(object):
    '''
    Delay Components Class
    '''

    def __init__(self, **delays):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        self.prop_delay = round(float(delays['prop_delay']), 2)
        self.trans_delay = round(float(delays['trans_delay']), 2)
        self.proc_delay = round(float(delays['proc_delay']), 2)
        self.queue_delay = round(float(delays['queue_delay']), 2)
        self.delay = (self.prop_delay + self.proc_delay +
                      self.trans_delay + self.queue_delay)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self.__dict__[key] = value
        if (key in ("prop_delay", "trans_delay",
                    "proc_delay", "queue_delay")):
            self.delay = (self.prop_delay + self.proc_delay +
                      self.trans_delay + self.queue_delay)
```

This seems to serve the purpose well, but when I create an object of `DelayComponents` for the first time, since `__setattr__` has been overridden and is called for each of the values being created, the `if` check inside `__setattr__` throws an error saying the remaining three variables have not been found (which is true, since they have not yet been created).

How do I resolve this dependency?

Also, is there some way to accomplish the same with a `dict`? More specifically, if the three variables were actually key-value pairs in a dict, where the third key's value was the sum of the values of the first two keys, would it be possible to update the third value automatically when either of the first two changes?

Comment: You could use e.g. `sympy` to set up and manage the equations.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't see how SymPy helps me automatically resolve dependencies. If I understand the documentation correctly, you will still need to execute solve() on the equations. Could you be more specific about your suggestion please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want zero default values for the unset `_delay`s (in both `__init__` and `__setattr__`) you could do something like:

```
class DelayComponents(object):
    '''
    Delay Components Class
    '''

    ATTRS = ['prop_delay', 'trans_delay', 'proc_delay', 'queue_delay']

    def __init__(self, **delays):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        for attr in self.ATTRS:
            setattr(self, attr, round(float(delays.get(attr, 0)), 2))
        # No point in setting delay here - it's already done!

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        super(DelayComponents, self).__setattr__(key, value)
        # This avoids directly interacting with the __dict__
        if key in self.ATTRS:
            self.delay = sum(getattr(self, attr, 0) for attr in self.ATTRS)
```

In use:

```
>>> d = DelayComponents(prop_delay=1, trans_delay=2, proc_delay=3, queue_delay=4)
>>> d.delay
10.0
```

Should you want different defaults for different attributes, `DelayComponents.ATTRS` could be a dictionary `{'attribute_name': default_value, ...}`.

---

A much simpler alternative is to make `delay` a `@property`, that is calculated only as required:

```
class DelayComponents(object):
    '''
    Delay Components Class
    '''

    ATTRS = ['prop_delay', 'trans_delay', 'proc_delay', 'queue_delay']

    def __init__(self, **delays):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        for attr in self.ATTRS:
            setattr(self, attr, round(float(delays.get(attr, 0)), 2))

    @property
    def delay(self):
        return sum(getattr(self, attr, 0) for attr in self.ATTRS)
```

---

To answer your sub-question: no, there's no way to do this with a vanilla `dict`; the values for keys aren't reevaluated based on changes to the values from which they're calculated.

---

Also, in all seriousness, there is no point to your current docstrings; you might as well leave them out entirely. They provide no information, and aren't compliant with [PEP-257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) either.

Comment: Thanks a ton for that clear explanation. And my docstrings were not being used them for anything. This is just test code. :)